# Function runs repeatedly for no apparent reason

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that is supposed to average integers together, and also check if a number is negative when it is input. Everything seems to work, until it's time to return a value, then it appears to run my function repeatedly and I have no idea why. I would google my issue, but I don't even know what to look up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double averageOrNegative(int sum, int counter);
int main(){
    int  sum = 0, counter = 0;
    double number = averageOrNegative(sum,counter);
    return 0;
}
double averageOrNegative(int sum, int counter){//the sum and counter are declared outside the function so they don't get reset when I call it again
    int input = 0;
    double result = 0;
    char yesORno = ' ';
    printf("\nPlease input a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input >= 0){
            counter++;
            sum = sum + input;
            printf("\ndo you want to input another number, press y for yes\n");
            scanf(" %c", &yesORno);
                if(yesORno == 'y'){
                    averageOrNegative(sum, counter);//this prompts for another number by calling the function again
                }else{
                    result = sum/counter;//this averages the numbers together and returns the result
                }
        }else{
            result = input;//if the number was negative, it becomes the return value
        }
    printf("\n%d", sum);
    printf("    %d", counter);
    printf("\nthis is being run\n");//these 4 lines are only here to test
    printf("\n%f", result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please use the title to communicate the problems with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function runs repeatedly because it is recursive (it calls itself) and all those `printf` are being executed every time the function is called.
If you want to print only the end result, do it in `main` like this:
`printf("%f\n", number);`

I'm not sure what are you trying to do here, but if what you want is to print the partial average every time you introduce a number, then you should do the printing before calling the function recursively. Otherwise you will get all the printing when you finish entering numbers.

My last advice to you is that you should mind about structure and organization in your code. It seems messy.